# How to install latest version of chromium via ppa repository

Tags: installation, google-chrome, chromium

I want to install latest version of chromium in my Ubuntu desktop 12.04. Please guide me How to install latest version of chromium via ppa repository.

Comment: May be y-ppa-manager and it's deep search mode would be helpful.

Comment: I just want to install a latest version of Chromium.